# Getting "unexpected end of file" error while parsing a XML document. How to get around this?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am getting unexpected end of file error while trying to parse below XML. As far as I have checked all the tags are properly closed. Any idea what may be wrong here? Below is the sample XML I am trying to parse. I have validated the XML in one of the online tools and it says the document is valid. But still cant parse it properly and getting the "end of file" error.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <env:Body>
        <wd:Submit_Customer_Invoice_Request
            xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
            wd:Add_Only="true"
            wd:version="v35.0">            
            <wd:Business_Process_Parameters>
                <wd:Auto_Complete>true</wd:Auto_Complete>
            </wd:Business_Process_Parameters>
            <wd:Customer_Invoice_Data>
                <wd:Customer_Invoice_ID>TEST_REF_1</wd:Customer_Invoice_ID>
                <wd:Submit>true</wd:Submit>
                <wd:Locked_in_Workday>false</wd:Locked_in_Workday>
                <wd:Company_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Company_Reference_ID">BCBSNC</wd:ID>
                </wd:Company_Reference>
                <wd:Currency_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Currency_ID">USD</wd:ID>
                </wd:Currency_Reference>
                <wd:Customer_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Customer_Reference_ID">07020-123456789</wd:ID>
                </wd:Customer_Reference>
                <wd:Invoice_Number>TEST-123456</wd:Invoice_Number>
                <wd:Invoice_Date>2020-11-25</wd:Invoice_Date>
                <wd:Document_Status>Approved</wd:Document_Status>
                <wd:Amount_Due>100.00</wd:Amount_Due>
                <wd:Customer_Invoice_Type_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Customer_Invoice_Type_ID">CUSTOMER_INVOICE_TYPE-6-12</wd:ID>
                </wd:Customer_Invoice_Type_Reference>
                <wd:Customer_Invoice_Line_Replacement_Data>
                    <wd:Customer_Invoice_Line_Reference_ID>Test_Ref_ID_12345</wd:Customer_Invoice_Line_Reference_ID>
                    <wd:Sales_Item_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Sales_Item_ID">SALES_ITEM-6-100</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Sales_Item_Reference>
                    <wd:Line_Item_Description>Duplicate Claim</wd:Line_Item_Description>
                    <wd:Quantity>1</wd:Quantity>
                    <wd:Unit_Cost>100.00</wd:Unit_Cost>
                    <wd:Worktags_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Cost_Center_Reference_ID">001</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Worktags_Reference>
                </wd:Customer_Invoice_Line_Replacement_Data>
            </wd:Customer_Invoice_Data>
        </wd:Submit_Customer_Invoice_Request>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: "...I am getting unexpected end of file error while trying to parse below XML..." Please provide more details how you  are doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The file you have posted is well-formed, so that leaves a number of possibilities:

(a) the error is coming from some other file

(b) you're submitting it to the XML parser incorrectly

(c) you're using a buggy XML parser

Whatever it is, you haven't supplied enough information for us to diagnose it.